# Ipython - plot pie chart from series with series table next to it

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, ipython

I have a matplotlib pie chart in Ipython notebook with a `plt.text` series table posted next to it.  The problem is the table is formated as series output and not as a nice table.  What am I doing wrong?

```
sumByGroup = df['dollar charge'].groupby(df['location']).sum().astype('int')

sumByGroup.plot(kind='pie', title='DOLLARS', autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.axis('off')
plt.text(2, -0.5, sumByGroup, size=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're calling groupby on `df['dollar change']` rather than the `df` as a whole. Try this instead,

```
sumByGroup = df.groupby(df['location']).sum().astype('int')

sumByGroup.plot(y='dollar charge', kind='pie', title='DOLLARS', autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.axis('off')
plt.text(2, -0.5, sumByGroup, size=12)
```

---

Full working example with made up data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


n = 20
locations = ['MD', 'DC', 'VA', 'NC', 'NY']

df = pd.DataFrame({'dollar charge': np.random.randint(28, 53, n),
                   'location': np.random.choice(locations, n),
                   'Col A': np.random.randint(-5, 5, n),
                   'Col B': np.random.randint(-5, 5, n)})

sumByGroup = df.groupby(df['location']).sum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sumByGroup.plot(y='dollar charge', kind='pie', title='DOLLARS',
                autopct='%1.1f%%', legend=False, ax=ax)
ax.axis('off')
ax.text(2, -0.5, sumByGroup, size=12)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

[image]